# TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

After running this line im getting the following error:
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

```
df[~(  (pd.np.isclose(df.Sizes.round(3), df.Volumes))  & (df['color'] == 'Blue')   )]
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: `isclose` only works for numbers - the `isfinite` test is for floats.  What's the dtype for `df.Sizes` and `df.Volumes`?

Comment: both are 'float64'

Comment: If that's all you can tell us about these arguments, then that's all the help we can give you!

Comment: they are numbers, that include decimals aswell , example (8.234), when rounding column Sizes the resulting rounded number is compared with the number in volumes column, and if they are equal it drops that row.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [152]: df=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12.).reshape(4,3), columns=['one','two','three'])                        
In [153]: df.three[:] = ['a',np.nan,4,3.2]                                                                   
In [154]: df                                                                                                 
Out[154]: 
   one   two three
0  0.0   1.0     a
1  3.0   4.0   nan
2  6.0   7.0     4
3  9.0  10.0   3.2
In [155]: pd.np.isclose(df.one.round(3), df.two)                                                             
Out[155]: array([False, False, False, False])
In [156]: pd.np.isclose(df.one.round(3), df.three)                                                           
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-156-d99a19b1d9b5> in <module>
----> 1 pd.np.isclose(df.one.round(3), df.three)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in isclose(a, b, rtol, atol, equal_nan)
   2520 
   2521     xfin = isfinite(x)
-> 2522     yfin = isfinite(y)
   2523     if all(xfin) and all(yfin):
   2524         return within_tol(x, y, atol, rtol)

TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

The test on two `float32` columns works, but raises this error when one column is object dtype with non-numeric values.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered such problem when I was comparing results of [two different functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70469480/how-to-accelerate-my-written-python-code-function-containing-nested-functions-f) (same in implementation with different writing styles; prepared [**medium data set**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14RJ0Ackx88NzQWloops5FagzuNQYDSrh/view?usp=sharing) in the aforementioned link was used for the evaluations), although all the data in the resulted arrays were of the same type *`np.float64`* (it was checked by looping on each value by `assert type(result[i]) == np.float64` too; Moreover, arrays were of the same type too with the same shape). I solved the problem just by specifying types for the arrays, again, ***manually*** using `.astype(np.float64)`. So, in my tests:

```
ex = elapses(r, pos, gap, ends_ind, elem_vert, contact_poss)
new = elapses_numba(r, pos, gap, ends_ind, elem_vert, contact_poss)

np.allclose(ex, new)                                            ----> The error
np.allclose(ex.astype(np.float64), new.astype(np.float64))      ----> True
```

In your code, something like the following change may be the solution (*if we checked that all the values are `np.float64` but getting the error yet*):

```
np.isclose(df.Sizes.round(3).astype(np.float64), df.Volumes.astype(np.float64))
```