# Getting error while trying to find the infinty values in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to find which column of my dataframe has infinity values since my regression model is throwing an error.

I used following command:

```
col_name = df.columns.to_series()[np.isinf(df).any()]
print(col_name)
```

I encountered following error:

```
ufunc 'isinf' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57207108/typeerror-ufunc-isfinite-not-supported-for-the-input-types-and-the-inputs-co?rq=1 Maybe you can try this

Comment: It looks like one of your columns is not numeric type. Check what `df.info()` returns first.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have a special pandas null type (like pd.NA) in your DataFrame, which numpy does not know what to do with.

I ran into the same issue when trying to replace my non-finite value check, as I am seeing **FutureWarning: use_inf_as_na option is deprecated** (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/34093). If you have an earlier version of pandas you could try comparing the results with this option enabled and disabled.

```
with pd.option_context('mode.use_inf_as_na', True):
     not_finite = pd.isna(vals)
```

If you know you have all numeric data, consider trying to replace pd.NA (object type) into np.NaN (float type) which numpy should be able to handle normally.

```
df_temp = df.where(pd.notnull(df), np.nan)  # Replace pd.NA, np.nan and None by np.nan
col_name = df_temp.columns.to_series()[np.isinf(df_temp).any()]
```